# Can Nioh for PC be played with keyboard/mouse?

Tags: pc, nioh

I have Nioh for PC. It works perfectly with the xbox controller. When I try to play with keyboard & mouse, only the keyboard works; the mouse does not. Can you play Nioh for PC with a mouse?

Comment: @Roijan Thanks for edit my post. My English is terrible, i learning but is very dificult to communicate. At least I understand almost everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nioh does not support mouse configuration as mentioned [here](https://techraptor.net/content/pc-version-of-nioh-does-not-have-mouse-support)

The article states:

> A recent press release from KOEI TECMO America and Team NINJA, reveals that the PC release of Nioh does not have mouse support. Dubbed Nioh: Complete Edition, it’s stated that while the title does support a keyboard, it’s best played via a game controller.

EDIT: I did some further looking. There is a mod which I found through a [steam forum post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/485510/discussions/0/1479857071273230795/) It talks about the fact that it is possible and then links to a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUsKfxF0JuA). With a slightly older version [GPDSCK 3.1](http://www.mediafire.com/file/x2eaf240lwal9wj/GPDSCK+3.1.rar)

In the description there is a link to a [new video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kb8t6bJTvC8) with a mediafire file with the latest version [GPDSCK v3.3b](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tx0v4ttf1b7vv2h/GPDSCK+3.3b.rar)

Now I do not own Nioh myself. But from the amount of people commenting on it. This seems like the best solution as of now.

EDIT 2: as @Nolonar mentioned. There has indeed been [an official update](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2017/11/28/nioh-mouse-support/) regarding Nioh's mouse support. You will however need to rebind the keys. I suggest you check the options menu in the game and check if it is possible.

Comment: Apparently, there's an official update incoming (if not already released), which adds mouse support to the game.

Comment: I shall look for an exact date , if true add that info